# PhoneGap - Styles and themes in Android app

Tags: android, cordova, android-actionbar

I'm building an Android app using PhoneGap, and would like to make the copy/share menu that shows up after a long click on text to overlay the app. To do so, I have to set `android:windowActionBar` to `true`. This is what docs say:

> Beware that hiding and removing the action bar causes your activity to
>   re-layout in order to account for the space consumed by the action
>   bar. If your activity regularly hides and shows the action bar (such
>   as in the Android Gallery app), you might want to use overlay mode.
>   Overlay mode draws the action bar on top of your activity layout
>   rather than in its own area of the screen. This way, your layout
>   remains fixed when the action bar hides and re-appears. To enable
>   overlay mode, create a theme for your activity and set
>   android:windowActionBarOverlay to true.

So I tried to apply this theme:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

to my application:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/icono_p"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

with no success.

Is there any way to set `android:windowActionBar` to `true` in a PhoneGap application?

EDIT:

The theme is actually being applied, but it just doesn't work as expected, the bar keeps resizing the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was that the copy/share menu is not an action bar, but a contextual action bar shown when the [contextual action mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB) starts. So, instead of `android:windowActionBar`, the property to be set to `true` is `android:windowActionModeOverlay`

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you would have to write a plugin for that for lower android versions. I am not sure since when this function is available but on my ICS 4.0 i can just copy and share any text out of any phonegap app without declaring anything special. its a system function and it should just work the same way you would copy and share text out of a standard browser.
what are you testing it on and which version?